# Can I temporarily disable the @@ replacement in LaTeX3?

Tags: best-practices, latex3, l3doc

I'm trying to write my L3 packages using good practice, which I understand involves using `@@` in defining command and variable names which then get replaced by the module name (Section 3.2.2 in `texdoc l3doc`).

However, I sometimes need to interact between L3 and L2e and L2e code is simply littered with `@`s and sometimes `@@`s (to be clear, these come from other code that I'm interfacing with so I don't have a choice about those).

So, to my question: Is there a way to temporarily disable the `@@` replacement?

If not, my current work around for, say, calling a macro defined in another package, is to use:

```
\use:c {commandWith@ @sInIt}
```

Note the extra space between the `@`s which is removed by L3 due to its habit of ignoring spaces.  I'd similarly use `:c` variants with token lists and the like.

Is there something better?

Comment: Thanks to the "Related" list, I've found https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497410/86 which looks sufficiently useful that it should be promoted to "Linked".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can go one of two ways

- Use `@@@@` to mean literal `@@` selectively: this is needed by the kernel istelf to define e.g. `\@@par`
- Use `%<@@=>` to turn off all substitution until you re-enable using `%<@@=something>`

Comment: Thank you! Both of these look very straightforward to use.